# bookModeling cannot be resolved

Tags: portlet, jsf-2.2, managed-property

my Error is :

```
"bookModeling" cannot be resolved
```

and my BookModeling:

```
public class BookModeling implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2117669648358293028L;
private String Book;
public String getBook() {
return Book;
}
public void setBook(String book) {
Book = book;
}
```

my BookManageBean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bookManageBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BookManageBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5646446743226853016L;
BookModeling bookModeling = new BookModeling();
}
```

my BookBackingBean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bookBackingBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BookBackingBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -552459151474443900L;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{bookManageBean}")
private BookManageBean bookManageBean;
public BookManageBean getBookManageBean() {
    return bookManageBean;
}
public void setBookManageBean(BookManageBean bookManageBean) {
    this.bookManageBean = bookManageBean;
}
```

And Where I am confronted with the error:

Comment: sorry: Where I am confronted with the error :::: <h:inputText value="#{bookBackingBean.bookManageBean.bookModeling.book}"/>

Comment: Where is the getter/setter pair for `bookModeling` in `bookManageBean`?